# How do i parse a regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am getting a regex value dynamically from a service in a string.
Eg:

```
String nameRegex = "^[0-9a-zA-Z\s\.]{3,40}$";
```

I want to parse this regex using Java.
So i have to replace `"\\"` with `"\\\\"` (i.e `\` with `\\`) but I get the following error:

> Unexpected internal error near index 1

How do I parse this regex?

Comment: Something is wrong here, as your Java string is not valid (single backslash `\s` is a control character).  What is the source of the regex string?

Comment: What input string are you trying to match?

Comment: if you are already getting it in `string` you dont need to replace `\` with `\\` that is just to escape \ in string definition but if you already have it then you dont need to do that

Comment: are you "getting" the regex as a java source code that must be compiled, that is, literally something like `String nameRegex = "^[a-z]$";`? or the regex like `^[a-z]$`?

Comment: @anubhava I am trying to parse string which contains 3 to 40 characters and no special character.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, i am getting the patterns dynamically and i have to use it against a particular input field for validation

Comment: Try: `nameRegex = "^[-.\\w\\s\\\\]{3,40}$";`

Comment: Yes what? please re-read my comment (if getting patteern, no changes must be done; if source code, backslashes must be escaped)

Comment: we can't see how you are trying it, hard to say whats wrong, best to include a [mcve]. Could use plain `.replace("\\", "\\\\")` to do the substitution (if really needed) {also note that there is no need to escape point inside `[]`}

Comment: If you are getting this regular expression dynamically from a service, it isn't a string literal, so you don't have to do any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is not that straight forward, as it depends on how you are getting your regular expression. If you are defining it in your code as `String` then you would just need to replace each `\` with `\\`, so your expression would look like this

```
String regex = "^[0-9a-zA-Z\\s\\.]{3,40}$";
```

If on the other hand you are pulling in from an external source (i.e. a Scanner) then you do not need to replace `\` with `\\`. For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String regex = sc.nextLine();
```

If you try and do a `replaceAll()` on this string, for example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String regex = sc.nextLine(); 
regex .replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
```

then this `replaceAll()` will produce a `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1` exception.